Not finding all drives in C# .NET 8.0 / .NET 9.0 using GetDrives()
I'm creating a file explorer to develop an image processing app. I'm using GetDrives() to start loading my treeview and it returns all internal drives, including the two on an internal NVME drive.
But it doesn't show any external drives -- until I put a disk in the CD-ROM drive, then it shows all attached drives both internal and external. The moment I remove the CD, it no longer sees the external drives.
Also, though not essential, any pointers as to recursively? load the subdirectories would help speed the dev, and much appreciated.
This is my code to date:
private void loadTree()
{
     treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

     try
     {
         // first get all available drives
         DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

         var driveCount = allDrives.Length;

         for (var d = 0; d < driveCount; d++)
         {
             treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(allDrives[d].Name));

             // Make a reference to a directory.
             DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(treeView1.Nodes[d].Text);

             // Get a reference to each directory in that directory.
             DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

             // Display the names of the directories.
             var dc = diArr.Length;
             for (var dr = 0; dr < dc; dr++)
             {
                 String currNode = diArr[dr].Name;
                 treeView1.Nodes[d].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(currNode));
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         // todo write handler
     }
}

// This is the modified code to overcome the exception thrown when accessing an empty drive.
private void loadTree()
{
     treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

     try
     {
         // first get all available drives
         DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

         var driveCount = allDrives.Length;

         var d = -1; 
         var nodeCount = -1;

         while (d < driveCount)
         {
             // increment the indexes
             d++; 
             nodeCount++;
             
             // Check the drive is ready to access
             DriveInfo thisDrive = new DriveInfo(allDrives[d].Name);

             if (thisDrive.IsReady)
             {
                 // Add the drive to the treeview
                 treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(thisDrive.Name));
                
                 // Make a reference to a directory.
                 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(thisDrive.Name);
                 
                 // Get a reference to each directory in that drive.
                 DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

                 // Display the names of the directories.
                 var dc = diArr.Length;

                 for (var dr = 0; dr < dc; dr++)
                 {
                     String currNode = diArr[dr].Name;
                     treeView1.Nodes[nodeCount].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(currNode));
                 }                        
             }
             else
             {
                 // decrement nodeCount to forestall treeview exception
                 nodeCount--;
                 continue;
             }                   
         }               
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         // todo write handler
     }
}


But it doesn't show any external drives -- until -- I put a disk in the cdrom drive -- just to clarify, is  it only the cdrom drive that isn't shown without a disk?  Or do you have multiple external drives including a USB drive and a cdrom drive and neither is shown until you insert a disk, whereupon both are shown?

Also, though not essential, any pointers as to [recursively?] load the subdirectories would help speed the dev, and much appreciated. -- the format for questions on stack overflow is one question per post, so you should ask another question.  That being said I did find Asynchronously Enumerate Folders and Is there an async version of DirectoryInfo.GetFiles / Directory.GetDirectories in dotNet?.

What DriveInfo you want to get when there isn't a medium inserted? The DriveInfo comes from that medium? If you want the "drive letter" for drives without a medium you should resort to Environment.GetLogicalDrives

If somehow all external drives are gone or there even if you fiddle with just one drive of those you might want to look at your system energy-saving mode or the ones for your usb controller  or drive itself.

For the recursive loading of subdirectories rethink if you really want it. That will take often a large amount of time. Typically (like Explorer) a tree view only shows one level of directories and then load the next one for a node if that node is expanded. It does not know all beforehand and would miss easily folders that are created after you loaded everything (and waited in worst case multiple minutes for that then maybe incomplete or wrong result).

Not to mention when there are recursive directory simlinks...
